# Create an array with a specified number of elements

Tags: php, arrays, loops, data-structures, populate

I am extremely new at php and I was wondering if someone could help me use either a `for()` or `while()` loop to create an array of 10 elements.

Comment: Ahh, the good old days ... if this question had been asked like this today, the user would be banned -

Comment: @user2835653 I hope the user would be asked, "What have you tried so far?" instead of banned right away. At least that's how I would have approached it.

Answer (score 27):

```
$array = array();
$array2 = array();

// for example
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $array[] = 'new element';
}

// while example
while (count($array2) < 10 ) {
    $array2[] = 'new element';
}

print "For: ".count($array)."<br />";
print "While: ".count($array2)."<br />";
```

Comment: Attributing keys in an array via $array[] = ...; is extremely slow. It's worth having the $i from the 'for' between the square braces. $array[$i] will give you a good boost in performance when compared to $array[] if you're attributing large datasets.

Comment: Alternatively one can use the array_push() function

Comment: @I GIVE... i found this to be incorrect, i ran a test based on up to 750,000 iterations and found $array[] to be faster than $array[$i] in all cases (granted the difference was a matter of thousandths of a second)

Answer (score 15):

A different approach to the `for` loop would be...

```
$array = array();

foreach(range(0, 9) as $i) {
    $array[] = 'new element';
}

print_r($array); // to see the contents
```

I use this method, I find it's easier to glance over to see what it does.

As *strager* pointed out, it may or may not be easier to read to you. He/she also points out that a temporary array is created, and thus is slightly more expensive than a normal for loop. This overhead is minimal, so I don't mind doing it this way. What you implement is up to you.

Comment: It'd be easy to read if you have a background in Python, but if you're from a C-style language background (in syntax, e.g. C++, Java, C#) this'll look strange to you.  Also, the code looks inefficient, creating a temporary array.

Comment: there are two inefficiencies one with using a foreach loop and a range statement where a simple for loop will suffice, the other is in using the array_push method which is 200% slower than the array[] statement (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559844/whats-better-to-use-in-php-array-value-or-array-pusharray-value)

Answer (score 6):

a bit easier to comprehend for a beginner maybe...

```
<?php


// for loop
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

$myArray[$i] = "This is element ".$i." in the array";

echo $myArray[$i];

}


//while loop
$x = 0;

while ($x < 10) {

$someArray[$x] = "This is element ".$x." in the array";

echo $someArray[$x];

$x++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what your purpose is here. PHP's arrays are dynamic, meaning that you can keep adding elements to them after they're created - that is, you don't need to define the length of the array at the start. I'll assume you want want to put 10 arbitrary things in an array.

for loop:

```
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $arr[] = "Element $i";
}
```

while loop:

```
$arr = array();
$i = 10;
while (--$i) {
    $arr[] = "Element $i";
}
```

by defining it:

```
$arr = array("Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3" ...);
```

Or if you just wanted a range of letters or numbers:

```
$arr = range(0, 9);
$arr = range('a', 'j');
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use [`array_fill()`](http://www.php.net/array_fill):

```
$array = array_fill(0, 10, 'Hello World');
```

But you should know that PHP arrays can be resized whenever you want anyway, I've never needed to create an array of a certain size.