# Which is faster in PHP, $array[] = $value or array_push($array, $value)?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

What's better to use in PHP for appending an array member,

```
$array[] = $value;
```

or

```
array_push($array, $value);
```

?

Though the manual says you're better off to avoid a function call, I've also read `$array[]` is much slower than `array_push()`. What are some clarifications or benchmarks?

Comment: $myArray[] = 123;

This will be faster than array_push function. It directly adds the value into that array.

Function has separate stack for that variables. and it may have that statement inside that function,.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

I personally feel like `$array[]` is cleaner to look at, and honestly splitting hairs over milliseconds is pretty irrelevant unless you plan on appending hundreds of thousands of strings to your array.

I ran this code:

```
$t = microtime(true);
$array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $array[] = $i;
}
print microtime(true) - $t;
print '<br>';
$t = microtime(true);
$array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    array_push($array, $i);
}
print microtime(true) - $t;
```

The first method using `$array[]` is almost 50% faster than the second one.

#### Some benchmark results:

```
Run 1
0.0054171085357666 // array_push
0.0028800964355469 // array[]

Run 2
0.0054559707641602 // array_push
0.002892017364502 // array[]

Run 3
0.0055501461029053 // array_push
0.0028610229492188 // array[]
```

This shouldn't be surprising, as the PHP manual notes this:

> If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] =  because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

The way it is phrased I wouldn't be surprised if `array_push` is more efficient when adding multiple values. Out of curiosity, I did some further testing, and even for a large amount of additions, individual `$array[]` calls are faster than one big `array_push`. Interesting.

Comment: I just always prefer to know which is the fastest way so when the day comes I will be asked to produce a high traffic site, I'll have some insight. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Micro-optimisations like these are rarely worth the effort. If you are writing it from scratch, do it how makes most sense, and only then, if it's a little slow to produce a page, profile it. The chances of getting all the way down to having to change something like this to speed things up is slight.

Comment: Your benchmark results are labelled the wrong way around

Comment: Just to make sure, since the code seems to mismatch the output, I verified that `$array[]` is indeed much faster, 300ms vs. 2000ms for 1M assignments on my machine. However, adding 20 items at once in array_push was about as fast as 20 `$array[] =`s.

Comment: @AlisterBulman Micro-optimizations are not worth the effort if you're thinking about going back through your whole codebase and 'optimizing' it. However, if you have several different ways of doing the same thing and are aware that one way is better (even just a little) than the others, you can make it your habit to use that way. Why wouldn't you do this?

Comment: @AlisterBulman I must strongly disagree, or at least partially, **if you know better, write better**, but don't put much effort to searching for *possible* micro-optimisation...

Comment: `array_push($array1,$array2)` may be better for those who are new to PHP simply because forgetting the brackets in the assignment can cause a very bad day. I personally use `$array1[] = $array2` however.

Comment: Reminder to any onlooker: not all minor optimization is the "premature optimization" that is the root of all evil as said Knuth. Some little faster things are just little faster things. remembering $array[]=$s is ok, combing your codebase for array_push isn't. Don't prematurely beat the premature-optimization-is-evil drum just because it exists.

Comment: Run on what hardware, operating system, and PHP version? The relative performance differences could depend on it. Also cold/warm run conditions, how is the measurement overhead accounted for, cache influence (L1/L2/L3), and whatever else is relevant.

Comment: benchmark is relevant for <=php5.5  ever since php 5.6 you can use the spread operator '...' and do array_push($array, ... $values);  If spread operator is possible there is really no need to compare between doing 10000 times $array[] = $value and a single array_push($array, ... $values).

Comment: "overhead calling a function"? if you look into PHP's C/C++ source-codes, both cause multiple C++ function-calls, and there should be no difference (but some magic causes difference).

Comment: "individual `$array[] = ...` calls are faster than one big `array_push(...)`"? I wonder how many arguments does `array_push(...)` need to be at last faster than `$array[] = ...` calls (if it is ever faster?).

Comment: I ran a test on PHP 8.2 on Wamp with 10000 items. `array_push($a,$item)` was around 16000 times slower (8000ms) than `$a[]=$item` (0.5ms). PHP 7.4.9 only showed a 3 times penalty for `array_push()` (2.2ms vs 0.6ms).

Answer (score 46):

The main use of array_push() is that you can push multiple values onto the end of the array.

It says in the [documentation](http://docs.php.net/array_push):

> If you use array_push() to add one
>   element to the array it's better to
>   use $array[] = because in that way
>   there is no overhead of calling a
>   function.

Comment: That's right.
Does anyone know a real world scenario where you have to add multiple values to an array at once? It seems to me that this must be a very rare scenario because I'm writing PHP since 2004 (where PHP4 was still actual) and I have never ever used it.

Answer (score 37):

From the [PHP documentation for `array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

Comment: Funny how your answer was first, but is the less voted on.

Answer (score 25):

Word on the street is that [] is faster because no overhead for the function call. Plus, no one really likes PHP's array functions...

"Is it...haystack, needle....or is it needle haystack...ah, f*** it...[] = "

Comment: Huh?  PHP's array functions are awesome.

Comment: Functionally they are awesome, yes, but he was referring to the inconsistent naming scheme.

Comment: You should turn on parameter hinting in your IDE. But I agree, some consistency would have been great.

Comment: Yeh I'd spend quite a bit more time on php's manual were it not for parameter hinting.. or intellisense as some programs call it I believe?

Comment: I do agree on this. There is no consistency neither in the naming scheme (x_y or xy or y_x ...) nor in the parameters *logic* (pass the target object first, last, between arrays, strings and regexps, good luck to find a common rule!).

Comment: It's not really an IDE, but I use Notepad++ (which has parameter hinting)

Comment: FWIW, I like the _needle/haystack_ naming convention and find it easy to remember, as it goes in the same order as the phrase: _"like finding a needle (1) in a haystack (2)"_

Comment: this inconsistent naming scheme does also exists for the string functions.
E.g. strlen, str_replace.

Comment: php functions are easy to understand... look:
    array_push( array, what to push );  |
    in_array( in, array );  |
    str_contains( string, contains );  |
    etc.  | EASY )

Comment: @AramKhachatryan back in 2009 we didn't have many programs like VS Code et al that automatically gave type hinting. It is "easy" now, but wasn't as such 14 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

One difference is that you can call array_push() with more than two parameters, i.e. you can push more than one element at a time to an array.

```
$myArray = array();
array_push($myArray, 1,2,3,4);
echo join(',', $myArray);
```

prints `1,2,3,4`

Answer (score 2):

A simple $myarray[] declaration will be quicker as you are just pushing an item onto the stack of items due to the lack of overhead that a function would bring.

Answer (score 2):

Since "**array_push**" is a function and it called multiple times when it is inside the loop, it will allocate memory into the stack.

But when we are using $array[] = $value then we are just assigning a value to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Second one is a function call so generally it should be slower than using core array-access features. But I think even one database query within your script will outweight 1000000 calls to `array_push()`.

See here for a quick benchmark using 1000000 inserts: https://3v4l.org/sekeV

Comment: Can you substantiate your claim, e.g. with some rough calculations? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2431648/edit), not here in comments (but ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

I just wan't to add : `int array_push(...)` returns
the new number of elements in the array ([PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-push.php)). which can be useful and more compact than `$myArray[] = ...; $total = count($myArray);`.

Also `array_push(...)` is meaningful when variable is used as a stack.