# array_push() one value into multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, push

I realize this may be a very simple question but I need to know how to add ONE value to multiple arrays in PHP. (The better way)

```
array_push($one, "hello");
array_push($two, "hello");
```

I need to do something like this (just as an example)

```
array_push($one && $two, "hello");
```

I have read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559844/whats-better-to-use-in-php-array-value-or-array-pusharray-value) question and seen the discussion if whether `$array[]` is better for speed, is it easier to use `$array[]`  for my specific problem?

Thanks in advance!! && please ask for any clarification needed!

Comment: BTW, that was me that posted that question linked :P

Comment: @alex lol had´n noticed that!

Comment: BTW Any answers using array_push?

Comment: See [my update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252978/php-array-push-one-value-into-various-array/4252990#4252990) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to do it would be...

```
$one[] = $two[] = 'hello';
```

[It works!](http://codepad.org/y3gYcUGl)

#### Update

> BTW Any answers using array_push? – Trufa

Sure.

```
$value = 'hello';
array_push($one, $value);
array_push($two, $value);
```

Though I would say using the `[]` syntax is easier :)

If you want to add multiple array members, it may be easier to use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$one = array_merge($one, array(
   'a',
   'b',
   'c'
));
```

You can also use the [`+` array operaror](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php), but it acts different (e.g. won't overwrite string keys from the left operand like `array_merge()` will).

```
$one += array(
   'a',
   'b',
   'c'
);
```

Comment: Alex thanks, but I´m actually doing that (in my code, the "hello" is just an example) for the array_push I just wanted to see if I could do it in one line, or most importantly using only ONE array_push

Comment: @Trua `array_push()` lets you append multiple members, but doesn't let you append those multiple members to multiple arrays on its own. It takes a reference to one array only.

Answer (score 2):

try `$one[] = $two [] = "hello";`

Comment: @Trua I think it is fair to say that they probably *didn't* see my answer when posting.

Comment: You are actually right, I´m sorry about that. So strange.. alex's appeared first when I refreshed, but the timestamp is there! :)

Comment: well its a 2 mins diff.. hehe.. its your call trufa

Comment: I accepted alex's answer because now it is more complete. Thanks a lot anyway, you've got my +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Why does it have to be on one line?
The below code works and is very readable:

```
$value = 'hello';
$one[] = $value;
$two[] = $value;
```

Comment: Your delimiters for the string do not match (`'`, `"`) - maybe you copied and pasted mine when I did the same thing first :P

Comment: I did copy/paste it to start with. Was working on other solutions (a loop over arrays, etc), then noticed the author seemed happy with your answer .

I still don't see the point of this question - why does he "need" to put things on one line. I think readability always trumps saving lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to "put it in one line" because I´m actually using array_push() so I didn't want to call it several times in different consecutive lines...

Comment: Yeah, readability *is* generally the most important thing. But I feel doing it like in my answer doesn't harm the readability much. Plus, you can skip the `$value` variable. :) +1 for your valid point of view.

Comment: the thing is that you answered my question using $array[] which makes it simple to add one value to multiple arrays but if i were to use the array push, I would have to do: array_push($one, "hello"); array_push($two, "hello"); ten times, this doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me, maybe its readable but its not very "nice"...