# Build new custom Array from Wordpress $wpdb->get_results array

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I'm currently taking the results of a table and using wp_send_json to using it as a JSON response.  The data is encoded as expected, however I'd like to tweak the output a bit by changing the keys, formating, and order.  I'm not sure how to rebuild the array and encode as json after so I'm looking for a little bit of help.

```
$stuff= $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_table"), ARRAY_A);
wp_send_json($stuff);
```

As of now the results I get via print_r look as follows.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => 1[gender] => Male[email] => test@loas . com[lat] => 38[long] => - 97[country_srt] => USA[country_long] => UnitedStates
    ) [1] => Array(
        [id] => 2[gender] => Female[email] => femal@test . com[lat] => 38[long] => - 97[country_srt] => USA[country_long] => UnitedStates
    )
)
```

When encoded I get:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "gender": "Male",
    "email": "test@loas.com",
    "lat": "45",
    "long": "-76",
    "country_srt": "USA",
    "country_long": "United States"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "gender": "Female",
    "email": "femal@test.com",
    "lat": "98",
    "long": "-34",
    "country_srt": "USA",
    "country_long": "United States"
}]
```

Thing is, I don't really need some of these values and also need to format some things to output for easy map plotting.  For instance the country longform and gender go into an html formatted string.  What I'm looking to do is transform this array to result in:

```
[ idhere: {
    "value": "1",
    "latitude": "45",
    "longitude": "-76",
    "tooltip": {"content":"HTML Showing gender variable and country variable"}
}, idhere: {
    "value": "2",
    "latitude": "98",
    "longitude": "-34",
    "tooltip": {"content":"HTML Showing gender variable and country variable"}
}]
```

Comment: then just change you query, and just include the columns you want

Comment: Change the way I query?  I'm not sure I follow this simplistic of an answer.

Comment: @Ghost limiting the query to the specific columns needed does not address the aspect of adding your own markup to the final json

Comment: @DrewT of course there's more to it, thats why its a comment :), and that `$count` is superfluous, just push it like you normally would do `$array[] = array here`

Comment: @Ghost running an incremental `$count` index is technically faster in performance than pushing to an array in php. See benchmarks in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559844/whats-better-to-use-in-php-array-value-or-array-pusharray-value It is also a peferred method because it helps with debugging the loop because you can output its value at any breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is break down the process down into steps (so you can change the data around) instead of sending your sql data to json directly.

1. build your own array
2. iterate over your sql result set while adding your own markup
3. send the output to json

something like:

```
$preJSON = array();    

// select only columns you need
$sql = "SELECT id, gender, country_srt, lat, long
        FROM wp_table"


$count = 0; // this is for $preJSON[] index

foreach( $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) as $key => $row ) {

    // each column in your row will now be accessible like this: 
    // $my_column = $row->column_name;
    // now we can do:

    $value = $row->id;
    $latitude = $row->lat;
    $longitude = $row->long;
    $gender = $row->gender;
    $country = $row->country_srt;
    $tooltip = array(
        "content" => "HTML and stuff" . $gender . "more HTML and stuff" . $country
    );

    // now we can build a row of this information in our master array
    $preJSON[$count] = array(
        "value" => $value,
        "latitude" => $latitude,
        "longitude" => $longitude,
        "tooltip" => $tooltip
    );

    // increment the index
    ++$count;
}

// after foreach
// send the whole array to json
$json = json_encode( $preJSON );
```

I believe this should be the basic gist of what you need

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but for some reason the array turns up empty.

Comment: Possibly you aren't getting the right `$key => $row` pair.  What happens if you try  `foreach( $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) as $row ) { print_r( $row ) }` if the query isn't empty it should show you the key pairs

Comment: The issue seems to be the *long* column in SQL.  Longitude contains negative numbers and when ever I try to just output that one column I get an empty array.  Is there some reason negative numbers wont print out and empty out an array?   It's the only difference I can see in all the columns.

Comment: @Mr.BigglesWorth I reallly need to know what happens you print out the whole $row as I suggested above. Otherwise, I am guessing when I offer suggestions. My guess is it sounds like you're not getting information in the correct type and it's breaking the loop. You can try string casting the row like: `$longitude = (string) $row->long;`

Comment: By the way, are you saying my answer works as long as you don't ask for the longitude row?

Comment: Yes sorry!  Your solution is perfect.  I just need to figure out why *long* creates an empty arrary.  In fact if I do a select all from the DB it works as well.

Comment: Oh nice, glad you are close to having it figured out. I have a feeling that string casting might fix this because something weird might be happening with the format you are getting back. When I look at your data array in your question I see the long node returning back as `[long] => - 97` and since there is a blank space between the `-` and the `97` I'm wondering if the `-` is being treated by php as a subtraction operator

Comment: I think that's it Drew.  Select all works in this case anyway since all columns are being used anyway, just would be nice to have the understanding behind it.  Thanks so much for the help!