# LEFT JOIN, add to array in PHP if results from second table exist

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, left-join

I am trying to expand the functionality of a dictionary I am building by showing definitions for some of the terms (if a definition exists).

I take the data from the two tables as follows:

```
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".DICTIONARY_TABLE." " .
            "LEFT JOIN ".DICTIONARY_DEFINITIONS." ON ".DICTIONARY_TABLE.".id = ".DICTIONARY_DEFINITIONS.".term_id ".
            "WHERE ".DICTIONARY_TABLE.".".$source." LIKE '%".$keyword."%' ".
            "AND ".DICTIONARY_TABLE.".theme_id = ".$selected_theme_id." ".
            "ORDER BY ".DICTIONARY_TABLE.".id");
```

After that, in the `while` loop, I first get the theme name (from another table), then add the query results to an array:

```
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // get theme name
    $theme_name = "theme_".$lang;
    $theme_query= $db->query("SELECT theme_id,".$theme_name." FROM ".DICTIONARY_THEMES." WHERE theme_id = ".$theme_id."");
    $theme_row  = $theme_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $theme      = $theme_row[$theme_name];

    // add all results to an array
    $results[] = array(
        'english'           => $row['english'],
        'bulgarian'         => $row['bulgarian'],
        'english_abbr'      => $row['english_abbr'],
        'bulgarian_abbr'    => $row['bulgarian_abbr'],
        'theme'             => $theme
    );
```

After that, I try to check if the `LEFT JOIN` has actually returned any results from the definitions table, and if yes, add those to the array as well - but this is where I fail...

```
    // check if definition exists for this term
    if(isset($row['bulgarian_definition'])) {
        array_push($results['bulgarian_definition'], $row['bulgarian_definition']);
    }
    if(isset($row['english_definition'])) {
        array_push($results['english_definition'], $row['english_definition']);
    }
```

I've tried all ways I could find to first check if the variables have been defined, and then push them to the `$results` array. Nothing works.

I don't seem to be able to successfully find out of `english_definition` and/or `bulgarian_definition` are set. When I run the query itself in PhpMyAdmin, it works just fine.

The only "solution" I can think of is to scrap the idea of having a separate table for the definitions and just expand the main table, but that's not a great approach I know.
Any insight as to what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT: I've changed the way elements are added to the array:**

```
    // check if definition exists for this term
    if(isset($row['bulgarian_definition'])) {
        $results['bulgarian_definition'] = $row['bulgarian_definition'];
    }
    if(isset($row['english_definition'])) {
        $results['english_definition'] = $row['english_definition'];
    }
```

And this now does the trick. When I dump the `$results` array outside of the `while` loop, both definitions have been added.

However, I now get a large number of `Warning: Illegal string offset 'theme' in...` and 'english' and 'bulgarian' - this happens below, when I run the $results array in a foreach loop to start printing them:

```
    foreach($results as $result) {

    if($theme != $result['theme']) {
        $theme = $result['theme'];
        $search_results .= "<h3>" . $result['theme'] . "</h3>";
    }

    if($source == "english") {
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            $result['english'] = preg_replace("|($keyword)|Ui", "<span style=\"color:#780223\">" . $keyword . "</span>", $result['english']);
        }
```

No idea yet why this happens, will keep looking.

SECOND EDIT: Decided to put the two definitions directly inside the $results array as follows:

```
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // get theme name
    $theme_name = "theme_".$lang;
    $theme_query= $db->query("SELECT theme_id,".$theme_name." FROM ".DICTIONARY_THEMES." WHERE theme_id = ".$theme_id."");
    $theme_row  = $theme_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $theme      = $theme_row[$theme_name];

    // add all results to an array
    $results[] = array(
        'english'           => $row['english'],
        'bulgarian'         => $row['bulgarian'],
        'english_abbr'      => $row['english_abbr'],
        'bulgarian_abbr'    => $row['bulgarian_abbr'],
        'theme'             => $theme,
        'bulgarian_definition'  => $row['bulgarian_definition'],
        'english_definition'    => $row['english_definition']
    );  
}// end while
```

This now works just fine. When I dump the array, if no definition exists, I have `'english_definition' => null` and if a definition exists, it's there. So far so good.

The new problem is that I can no longer group the results by theme - the theme of the last result found is shown. Which is a different problem altogether. What really irks me is that before I added the definitions, everything worked just fine. You can the working website [here](http://dictionary.asphodel-works.com/).

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

1. Decided against pushing values to the array (as shown above).
2. Got rid of the extra query within the `while` loop that gets the theme's name, moving it instead to the query that performs the search. Thus the query itself is:

   ```
                   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".DICTIONARY_TABLE." " .
           "JOIN ".DICTIONARY_THEMES." ON ".DICTIONARY_TABLE.".theme_id = ".DICTIONARY_THEMES.".theme_id ".
           "LEFT JOIN ".DICTIONARY_DEFINITIONS." ON ".DICTIONARY_TABLE.".id = ".DICTIONARY_DEFINITIONS.".term_id ".
           "WHERE ".DICTIONARY_TABLE.".".$source." LIKE '%".$keyword."%' ".
           "ORDER BY ".DICTIONARY_TABLE.".theme_id, ".DICTIONARY_TABLE.".id");
   ```

And the `while` loop is:

```
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $theme_name = "theme_".$lang;

    // add all results to an array
    $results[] = array(
        'english'           => $row['english'],
        'bulgarian'         => $row['bulgarian'],
        'english_abbr'      => $row['english_abbr'],
        'bulgarian_abbr'    => $row['bulgarian_abbr'],
        'theme'             => $row[$theme_name],
        'bulgarian_definition'  => $row['bulgarian_definition'],
        'english_definition'    => $row['english_definition']
    );  
}// end while
```

The website link from above will now load the upgraded search functionality, where definitions will be shown (if they exist). One example word for anyone curious is "worm".

As it turns out, sometimes all it takes to fix a problem is to show it to people and then start thinking about it, as sometimes the solution is right in front of you. Thanks to all who participated!

Comment: Please show us the code where you filled in the $row array

Comment: Have you done a `print_r($results)` to see the `array_push()` worked, but just added them as new array elements, instead of added them to the `$result[]` that you created in the loop.

Comment: Yes, I do a `print_r($results)` but `array_push` doesn't add the new elements - because both `english_definition` and `bulgarian_definition` are NULL, I suppose. Neither does `$results[] = $row['english_definition']`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** *Deleted previous answer since it was incorrect. Will update this answer once I have a solution to the problem. Have not deleted this answer since I haven't found the option that does so. Though sometimes it is fun to take up space and feel important :), don't hate the player, hate the game.*

---

Comment: look at the query for `$theme_query`, it is `SELECT theme_id,".$theme_name." FROM ...`. So those columns are not in `$theme_row`, but in `$row` which is the outer loop variable.

Comment: @Sean You are correct. I commented on his question to display the code where he fills in the $row array, I'll edit my answer now considering the new info.

Comment: On your second part - `$results[] = array(` is correct if you are adding the array on each loop of `while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`. If they have more than 1 row returned, it needs to be `$result[]`, as with `$result` only on each loop iteration it would overwrite the previous value, and only the last loop value(s) would be saved.

Comment: @Sean so if I have an array called `$result` that had information in it already, and I wanted to add rows to it, I could then use `$result[] = array(...)` and that would give me the same result as `array_push($result, array(...))`?

Comment: Yes. I prefer `$result[]` over `array_push()`, but they basically do the same thing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559844/whats-better-to-use-in-php-array-value-or-array-pusharray-value

Comment: @Sean and there goes all of my answer. I actually learned more from cheeseus's question than he did. Might not be fair, but then who said the world was meant to be fair?