# Split array but sum of each array not to exceed a max value else push to next array index

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, Array 1 being a donor array which has a series of values (not necessarily equal values as in my example). Array 2 is the desired result and would store a series of sub arrays with values from Array 1 where each sub array's total sum would not exceed 25. If it does, the excess would get pushed to the next index in Array 2 where the rules would also apply.

**Donor array (Array 1):**

```
$a1=array(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10);
```

**Desired output (Array 2):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10,10,5
    [1] => 5,10,10
    [2] => 10,10,5
    [3] => 5,10,10
)
```

Here the code I tried but it gets an error:

> **Notice: Undefined offset:** 10...etc.

```
$a1=array(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10);
$a2=array();
$count=count($a1);

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $a2count=array_sum($a2);

    if($a2count>25){
        $i=$i+1;
        $a2[$i]=$a1[$i];
    }
    else{
        $a2[$i]=$a1[$i];
    }
}

print_r($a2);
```

I don't know what logic to implement and get result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: The logic is not so hard. Hope it helps.

```
   <?php 

   $a1=array(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10);

   $a2 = [];
   $a3 = [];

   $m = 0;

   for($i = 0; $i < count($a1); ++$i){      

        $m += $a1[$i];

        if($m > 25){

           $n = $m % 25;

           if(array_sum($a2) != 25){

               $a2[] = $n;

           }


           $a3[] = implode(',', $a2);       

           $a2 = []; 

           $m = $n;

           $a2[] = $n;


         } else{

           $a2[] = $a1[$i];

         }


   }

   $a3[] = implode(',', $a2);

   print_r($a3);

   ?>
```

Comment: down vote couse using `array_push`, `array_push($a2, $n)` equals `$a2[]=$n` [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559844/whats-better-to-use-in-php-array-value-or-array-pusharray-value)

Comment: @Kinshuk Lahiri  if i give the array 1 values more than 25 ,it disappers just check it with **array(23,2,2,23,50,50)**

Comment: need to add if condition where the remainder is 0.  `if($n == 0){
     
       $n = $m / $constant;

       $n = $m / $n;
             
     }`

Comment: @Kinshuk Lahiri thanks for u r effort.  Its working but last index values is not splitting in array2 check with **array(50,50,50)** only first two elements splitting

Comment: @Vivil Yeah I know that. That's the reason I haven't updated it in the code yet. Will check it. Currently working.

Answer (score 2):

Mayhaps something like this will work for you. I will notate so it's not just a copy-and-paste answer. Maybe someone will get some insight on it to improve it in the future:

```
function slitArray($a1,$num = 25)
    {
        # Used to store the difference when the value exceeds the max
        $store  =   0;
        # Storage container that will be built using sums/diffs
        $new    =   array();
        # Loop through the main array
        foreach($a1 as $value) {
            # If the last key/value pair in our return array is an array
            if(is_array(end($new)))
                # Add up the values in that array
                $sum    =   array_sum(current($new));
            else
                # If not array, no values have been stored yet
                $sum    =   0;
            # This just gets the last key
            $count      =   (count($new)-1);
            # Assign last key
            $i          =   ($count <= 0)? 0 : $count;
            # If the sum of the current storage array plus the value
            # of the current array is greater than our max value
            if(($sum + $value) > $num) {
                # Take max and remove the current total of storage array
                $use            =   ($num-$sum);
                # Take what's left and remove it from the current value
                $store          =   ($value-$use);
                # If the current stored value (the value we want to push to
                # the next storage k/v pair) is more than the max allowed
                if($store > $num) {
                    # Takes a value, checks if it's greater than max,
                    # and if it is, breaks the value up by max as a divider
                    $divide =   function($store,$num)
                        {
                            if($store > $num) {
                                $count  =   ceil($store/$num);
                                for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
                                    $new[]  =   ($store > $num)? $num : $store;
                                    $store  -=  $num;
                                }

                                return $new;
                            }
                            else
                                return array($store);
                        };
                    # This should either be an array with 1 or more values
                    $forward    =   $divide($store,$num);
                    # Do a look forward and add this excess array into our
                    # current storage array
                    $a          =   $i; 
                    foreach($forward as $aVal) {
                        $new[$a+=1][]   =   $aVal;
                    }
                }
                # If the store value is less than our max value, just add
                # it to the next key in this storage array
                else {
                    $new[$i+1][]    =   $store;
                    # Reset the storage back to 0, just incase
                    $store          =   0;
                }
            }
            # Set the current "use" value as the current value in our
            # from-array. Since it doesn't exceed the max, it just gets
            # added to the storage array
            else
                $use    =   $value;
            # Sometimes the math makes $use 0, keep that out of the
            # storage array. The $use value is the current value to add at
            # the time of iteration. Previous storage values are added as
            # future-keys
            if($use > 0)
                $new[$i][]      =   $use;
        }
        # Return the final assembled array
        return $new;
    }

# To use, add array into function
$a1 =   array(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10);
# to split using different max value, just add it to second arg
# example: slitArray($a1,20);
print_r(slitArray($a1));
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 10
        )
)
```

An array input of:

```
$a1 =   array(23,2,71,23,50,2,3,4,1,2,50,75);
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => 6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 19
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 19
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

)
```

Comment: yes bro , this also works i will update my answer thanks bro

Comment: Bro if i give the value less than 25 means working perfectly .  But  greater than 25 is adding the arrays in last just check it with **array(23,2,2,23,50,50);**

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you a bit using Pseudocode:

```
ar1 = {10,10,10,20,40,[0]=>1,[0]=>3,[0]=>4};

ar2 = new array (ar.length) \\ worst case

int c = 0; \\current

foreach (ar1 as $value){

ar2 [c]+=ar1[i];

if (ar2 [c]>25){ c++;}

}
```

---

Logic behind the code:

`Add` the value of `ar1[i] to` the current `ar2` value till it passes `your limit` (25 in this case). `If` it exceeds you boundary, `than` move to the `next` value in the goal array. The `worst case` would be, that every value is over 25, so it would be an `exact copy` of the original array.

---

Here the php code:

```
$ar1=array(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10);

$ar2 = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

$c = 0;

foreach( $ar1 as $key => $value ){

    $ar2[$c]=$value+$ar2[$c];

    if ($ar2[$c]>25){$c++;}

}
```

Comment: i m waiting @TheRealVira

Comment: @Vivil done - seems a bit shorter than the other ones - I also thought you'd want to get the sum of the numbers of the `ar1` array, so here you go! Hope it's still helpfull :)

Comment: its adding only i want the index values to insert.  if it is reached 25 it should split into two. pls see the @Rasclatt answer

Answer (score 0):

The final code for this question

```
<?php 
function slitArray($a1,$num = 25)
{
  $store  =   0;
  $new    =   array();

  foreach($a1 as $value) {

    if(is_array(end($new)))
      $sum    =   array_sum(current($new));
    else
      $sum    =   0;

    $count      =   (count($new)-1);
    $i          =   ($count <= 0)? 0 : $count;

    if(($sum + $value) > $num) {
      $use            =   ($num-$sum);
      $store          =   ($value-$use);
      if($store > $num) {
    $divide =   function($store,$num)
      {
        if($store > $num) {
          $count  =   ceil($store/$num);
          for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $new[]  =   ($store > $num)? $num : $store;
        $store  -=  $num;
          }

          return $new;
        }
        else
          return array($store);
      };

    $forward    =   $divide($store,$num);
    $a          =   $i; 
    foreach($forward as $aVal) {
      $new[$a+=1][]   =   $aVal;
    }
      }
      else {
    $new[$i+1][]    =   $store;
    $store          =   0;
      }
    }
    else
      $use    =   $value;

    if($use > 0)
      $new[$i][]      =   $use;
  }

  return $new;
}

$a1 = array(10,20,30,40,50,60);

$arr=slitArray($a1);

print_r($arr);

?>
```