# Split array(both Integer and characters) but sum of each array not to exceed a max value else push to next array index

Tags: php, arrays

Here I am updating this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888157/split-array-but-sum-of-each-array-not-to-exceed-a-max-value-else-push-to-next-ar/39889083#39889083) question. There are two arrays, Array 1 being a donor array which has a series of values . Array 2 is the desired result and would store a series of sub arrays with values from Array 1 where each sub array's total sum would not exceed 25. If it does, the excess would get pushed to the next index in Array 2 where the rules would also apply. Already only with integer values  successfully splited. If array has both integer and characters how can be split.

**Donor array (Array 1):**

```
$a1=array('aaa10','bbb20','ccc30','ddd40','eee50');
```

**current output (Array 2): (with only giving integer values in array)**

```
$a1=array(10,20,30,40,50);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

)
```

**Desired output (Array 2):**

```
$a1=array(aaa10,bbb20,ccc30,ddd40,eee50);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [aaa] => 10
            [bbb] => 15   
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bbb] => 5
            [ccc] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ccc] => 10
            [ddd] => 15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ddd] => 25
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [eee] => 25
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [eee] => 25
        )
)
```

***Here the code***

```
function slitArray($a1,$num = 25)
{
  $store  =   0;
  $new    =   array();

  foreach($a1 as $value) {

    if(is_array(end($new)))
      $sum    =   array_sum(current($new));
    else
      $sum    =   0;

    $count      =   (count($new)-1);
    $i          =   ($count <= 0)? 0 : $count;

    if(($sum + $value) > $num) {
      $use            =   ($num-$sum);
      $store          =   ($value-$use);
      if($store > $num) {
    $divide =   function($store,$num)
      {
        if($store > $num) {
          $count  =   ceil($store/$num);
          for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $new[]  =   ($store > $num)? $num : $store;
        $store  -=  $num;
          }

          return $new;
        }
        else
          return array($store);
      };

    $forward    =   $divide($store,$num);
    $a          =   $i; 
    foreach($forward as $aVal) {
      $new[$a+=1][]   =   $aVal;
    }
      }
      else {
    $new[$i+1][]    =   $store;
    $store          =   0;
      }
    }
    else
      $use    =   $value;

    if($use > 0)
      $new[$i][]      =   $use;
  }

  return $new;
}
$a1=array(10,20,30,40,50); 
$arr=slitArray($a1);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: In desired output i have given like key value pair it does'nt matter it can also like                                                                                                    ** Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaa10
            [1] => bbb15   
        )) **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified `splitArray` function: (Read the inline comments for explanation)

```
<?php

$a1 = array('aaa10','bbb20','ccc30','ddd40','eee50');

print_r(splitArray($a1, 25));

function splitArray($array, $max_sum) {

    // Create array with alpha key and numeric value
    array_walk($array, function($str) use (&$arr_formatted) {
        $arr_formatted[preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $str)] = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    });

    $resultantArr = [];

    // Function to fill the resulant array
    $array_operation = function($key, $no, $isMemory = FALSE) use(&$resultantArr, $max_sum, &$memory) {
        if($no <= $max_sum) {
            $resultantArr[][$key] = $no;
            // When the resultant array is filled with data in memory, clear the memory (no more needed!)
            if($isMemory)
                unset($memory[$key]);
        } else {
            $resultantArr[][$key] = $max_sum;
            $memory[$key] = $no - $max_sum;
        }
    };

    foreach ($arr_formatted as $key => $no) {
        if(count($resultantArr) == 0) {
            // Only for first iteration
            $array_operation($key, $no);
        } else {
            // Sum of the last element in array
            $sum = array_sum($resultantArr[key($resultantArr)]);
            if($sum <= $max_sum) {
                if(($no + $sum) <= $max_sum) {
                    $resultantArr[key($resultantArr)][$key] = $no;
                } else {
                    // When the count increases when the number is added, add the number that it can allocate
                    // Remaining is pushed to memory
                    $allocation = $max_sum - $sum;
                    if($allocation > 0) {
                        $resultantArr[key($resultantArr)][$key] = $allocation;
                    }
                    $memory[$key] = $no - $allocation;
                }
            } else {
                // Add the number to new index
                $array_operation($key, $no);
            }
        }

        // Allocate the values stored in memory
        while(isset($memory) && count($memory)) {
            foreach ($memory as $m_key => $m_no) {
                $array_operation($m_key, $m_no, TRUE);
            }
        }

        // Move the pointer to the last location
        end($resultantArr);
    }

    return $resultantArr;
}
```

See the working result [here](https://eval.in/659304).