# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create an overview of the first dates of every event. So the event-title must be unique. My idea was to create a helper-function where I loop over the result of my query and check the title of every item. To make sure every title passes only once, I want to push the title into an array ($checklist).  If it does not exist, I add that item to the result-array. If it does, just continue to the next item.

I always get the error:

```
in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given
```

This is my code:

```
function showFirstEvenst($collection) {
    $checklist = array();
    $result = array();

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $title = strtolower($item['events']['title']);

        if (!in_array($title, $checklist)) {
            $checklist = array_push($checklist, $title);
            $result = array_push($result, $item);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I already tried to cast $checklist and $result as array in the foreach loop but without result.

What do I need to change?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php returns an integer, and you overwrite your array in the loop

Comment: And why use `array_push()`??? Just `$checklist[] = $title;`

Comment: @AbraCadaver is that more performant?

Comment: @bflydesign it won't make a huge difference, but yes, it should be.

Comment: Not sure if more it's performant, but it certainly is more functional for your needs haha

Comment: Found this related question in regards to performance of `$array[] = $value` vs `array_push($value, $array)`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559844/whats-better-to-use-in-php-array-value-or-array-pusharray-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array_push function will return the count of array after an element is added to array. so dont assing the output of the function to array.

Replace

```
  if (!in_array($title, $checklist)) {
                $checklist = array_push($checklist, $title);
                $result = array_push($result, $item);
            }
```

with

```
 if (!in_array($title, $checklist)) {
               array_push($checklist, $title);
               array_push($result, $item);
            }
```

Comment: that is indeed the problem...wasn't looking for that.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @Lawrence Cherone and @Ravinder Reddy's answers, instead of using `array_push`, you could use native array syntax to push to the array:

```
if (!in_array($title, $checklist)) {
    $checklist[] = $title;
    $result[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: In fact, the array_push documentation recommends doing it this way when you're just appending one item.

Answer (score 2):

Its happening because within your loop your assigning `$checklist` with the value of `array_push()` which will be the new number of elements in the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php