# Uneffective loop in Laravel 8, time spent on each iteration is proportional to array size

Tags: php, laravel, loops, collections

In Laravel 8 / PHP 8, I receive a body in POST, transform the data, and bulk insert into TimescaleDB.

Here is the code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
        $body = $request->getContent();
        $meter = json_decode($body, true);
        $chunkSize = 1000;
        $measures = $meter['Measures'];
        $chunkedRaws = collect($measures)->chunk($chunkSize);
        $ok = 0;
        $nok = 0;
        $initialTime = Carbon::now();
        foreach ($chunkedRaws as $chunkNumber => $raws) {
            $chunkTime = Carbon::now();
            $rawsToInsert = [];
            foreach ($raws as $k => $raw) {
                $rawTime = Carbon::now();
                array_push($rawsToInsert, new \App\Models\Raw([
                    'operation_id' => $meter['OperationID'],
                    'meter_id' => $meter['ID'],
                    'conso_prod' => $meter['ConsoProd'],
                    'timestep' => $meter['Timestep'],
                    'unit' => $meter['Unit'],
                    'source' => $source,
                    'time' => Carbon::parse($raw['t'])->toIso8601ZuluString(),
                    'delta' => $raw['d'],
                ]));
               

            }
            // Insert into TimescaleDB cut
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => $ok . " Raws has been inserted,\n " . $nok . " Failed"], 200);
    }
```

The first time I call it, I have a body with 3744 elements.

It will take aprox 5-6ms for each element to push into the array so, 6 x 3744 / 1000 = 22 sec aprox.

But my second post has 26930 elements. Now,  each `array_push` will take aprox 52 ms, so 52 * 26930 / 1000 = 23 minutes aprox. Way to long.

the `array_push` should always be the same independently of how many rows there is in body ?

Why is the time spent on `array_push` proportional to the `$chunkedRaws` size ???

Comment: sidenote, have you tried replacing `array_push()` with `$rawsToInsert[] = ...` - see [speed benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559844/which-is-faster-in-php-array-value-or-array-pusharray-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare the object externally.
And as suggested above, you can stop using array_push

```
...

$raw = new \App\Models\Raw([
    'operation_id' => $meter['OperationID'],
    'meter_id' => $meter['ID'],
    'conso_prod' => $meter['ConsoProd'],
    'timestep' => $meter['Timestep'],
    'unit' => $meter['Unit'],
    'source' => $source, 
]);

foreach ($chunkedRaws as $chunkNumber => $raws) {
    $chunkTime = Carbon::now();
    $rawsToInsert = [];
    foreach ($raws as $k => $raw) {
        $rawTime = Carbon::now();
        // Here I'm assuming you have setter in your Raw object
        $raw->setTime(Carbon::parse($raw['t'])->toIso8601ZuluString());
        $raw->setDelta($raw['d']);
        $rawsToInsert[] = $raw;
    }
    // Insert into TimescaleDB cut
}

...
```